# AWT getPeer returns null

Tags: java, awt

I am new in AWT and I'm facing a problem. Here is the code sample of my function `func(Container container)`, where `container != null`:

```
Canvas embedder = new Canvas();
embedder.setBackground(...);
embedder.setPreferredSize(...);
container.add(embedder);
container.setVisible(true);
```

Then I am trying to get `frameWindow`, long
and my first action is

```
ComponentPeer peer = embedder.getPeer();
```

and I am getting `peer == null`

Please, tell me why this may happen?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want the peer? `java.awt.peer` has been disappeared and wasn't useful anyway. And use Swing, not AWT components.

But it's not there because the [heavyweight] component has not been realised [essentially put on the screen] yet.

Comment: Tom's right; presumably, the container that you're passing in to your method isn't yet visible on-screen. That is, it's not the child of a Window or Dialog that has itself been made visible on-screen.

On the other hand, of the container HAD belonged to some kind of visible window, then embedder WOULD have a peer, and you'd get a non-null answer.

In any event, Tom's first statement is REALLY useful. Think very, very hard about WHY you want the native peer. Then, think again...

Comment: I need to check particulary an AWT component, thats why i am using it.  `        JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame("frame", false, false, false, false);
        frame.setSize(220, 220); func(frame);` this is what i am using before calling my func. so, i can't get what i am missing here to make it work

Comment: i am not the one who wrote it, i need to fix it and make it work using AWT

Comment: +1 for the second statement, which helpfully answered the q. Tempted to downvote for "has been disappeared" (it's long been deprecated, but is still present in the latest release version) and "wasn't useful anyway" - that's a broad claim that contradicts a lot of useful examples. If you can tell me how to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855743/create-child-window-of-another-processs-hwnd-e-g-screensaver-preview without getPeer(), I'll be glad to be schooled!

Comment: @LarsH `java.awt.peer` is disappeared in the sense that http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/peer/package-summary.html is a 404.

Comment: @Tom: ok. I should have said "latest recommended version" rather than "latest release", which according to http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp is 1.6.0u31. And getPeer() is still there: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getPeer()